# TypeScript error: Property '...' is missing in type '...'

Tags: typescript

I'm running into a TypeScript error with this bit of code:

```
let event: KeyboardEvent = {
    preventDefault: () => { },
    stopPropagation: () => { },
    keyCode: 75
};
```

Where the error is:

`Type '{ preventDefault: () => void; stopPropagation: () => void; keyCode: number; }' is not assignable to type 'KeyboardEvent'.
  Property 'altKey' is missing in type '{ preventDefault: () => void; stopPropagation: () => void; keyCode: number; }'.`

I get it, it's TypeScript, it wants me to supply a full `KeyboardEvent`. But the full definition of `KeyboardEvent` is:

```
interface KeyboardEvent extends UIEvent {
    readonly altKey: boolean;
    readonly char: string | null;
    readonly charCode: number;
    readonly ctrlKey: boolean;
    readonly key: string;
    readonly keyCode: number;
    readonly locale: string;
    readonly location: number;
    readonly metaKey: boolean;
    readonly repeat: boolean;
    readonly shiftKey: boolean;
    readonly which: number;
    readonly code: string;
    getModifierState(keyArg: string): boolean;
    initKeyboardEvent(typeArg: string, canBubbleArg: boolean, cancelableArg: boolean, viewArg: Window, keyArg: string, locationArg: number, modifiersListArg: string, repeat: boolean, locale: string): void;
    readonly DOM_KEY_LOCATION_JOYSTICK: number;
    readonly DOM_KEY_LOCATION_LEFT: number;
    readonly DOM_KEY_LOCATION_MOBILE: number;
    readonly DOM_KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD: number;
    readonly DOM_KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT: number;
    readonly DOM_KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD: number;
}
```

That's a lot. And I'm creating this event for unittesting purposes, I only need the three properties. What is the proper way of dealing with this? I'm trying to avoid simply declaring it as `any` and I also really don't want to define 21 properties.

Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried double casting? (`evt:KeyboardEvent = ({...} as any) as KeyboardEvent`)

Comment: @olivarra1 Even just a simple single cast does the trick. `let event: KeyboardEvent = {
 preventDefault: () => { },
 stopPropagation: () => { },
 keyCode: 75
} as KeyboardEvent;`. Did not know TypeScript allowed that. Excellent find.

Comment: If you need only 3 properties you can define your own interface with only these 3 properties and use it throughout your code. Don't use real `KeyboardEvent`, just make sure that real events are assignable to yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try casting to desired type

```
let event: KeyboardEvent = {
    preventDefault: () => { },
    stopPropagation: () => { },
    keyCode: 75
} as KeyboardEvent;
```

Comment: Great answer, however, some link to documentation or explanation would be great